# Non-plane wave solutions to Dirac equation?

Tags: dirac-equation, plane-wave

Solutions to Dirac equation

$$(-i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+m)\psi=0$$

are usually obtained by acting from the left with complex conjugate Dirac operator

$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+m)(-i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+m)\psi=(-\partial^2+m^2)\psi=0$$

and realizing that this is a wave equation.
I wonder if the additional multiplication by $(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+m)$ above just restricts the full set of solutions to plane waves only, and so whether the original first order equation might have other types of solutions as well? Is it proven that plane waves are the complete set of solutions to the Dirac equation?

Comment: Anything which satisfies the Dirac equation also satisfies the Klein-Gordon equation, so this 'additional multiplication' is, if anything, going to give us *spurious* solutions rather than cause us to lose solutions. Indeed, we can take our plane wave solutions to the KG equation and substitute them back into the Dirac equation, and we will find an additional constraint on the components of $\psi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We first check that
   $$
   \psi(x)=\sum_s\int\mathrm d\vec k\ u_s(\vec k)c_{\vec k}\mathrm e^{-ikx}+v_s(\vec k)d_{\vec k}^\dagger\mathrm e^{ikx}\tag{1}
   $$
   is a solution of the Dirac equation. To do so, substitute this expression into $(-i\not\partial+m)\psi(x)$, and use $(\not p-m)u=(\not p+m)v=0$.
2. Second, we realise that the relation above can be inverted:
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   c^{s\dagger}_{\vec k}&=\int\mathrm d\vec x\ \mathrm e^{ikx}\psi^\dagger(x)u_s(\vec k)\\
   d^{s\dagger}_{\vec k}&=\int\mathrm d\vec x\ \mathrm e^{ikx}v^\dagger(\vec k)\psi(x)
   \end{aligned}\tag{2}
   $$
3. Finally, noting that the Dirac equation is linear, we see that $(1)$ **is indeed the most general solution**, as it solves any initial value problem (as per $(2)$).

**References**

Srednicki's book, http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html. For $(1)$ see page 239, and for $(2)$ see page 263.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking that being a four component equation, it roughly corresponds to a fourth order single component equation and would require four initial conditions to specify a solution. with the $c$ and $d$ we have two conditions... but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Kagaratsch it does require four initial conditions: the four components of $\psi(0,\vec x)$. You need these four functions of $\vec x$ to specify $\psi(x)$ for all $t$!

Comment: Oh, but don't we only have two constraints in your equation $(2)$? Is that sufficient to fix all four components in $\psi$ in the most general case?

Comment: @Kagaratsch recall that $u^\dagger \psi=u_1\psi^1+u_2\psi^2+u_3\psi^3+u_4\psi^4$, so that the inner products $u^\dagger\psi$ and $\psi^\dagger v$ contain the four functions $\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3,\psi_4$. You need to know these four functions to know the value of $c,d$. Once you calculate $c,d$ with $(2)$, you can plug their value back to $(1)$ to find $\psi$ for all $t$. But to use $(2)$ you need to known the initial value of the four components of $\psi$, thus four initial conditions. I hope it's clear now; otherwise tell me and I'll try to explain it again

Comment: I think the $c$ and $d$ are essentially the constants from the (decoupled) Klein-Gordon wave equation (like $f(x)=c e^{i {m} x}+d e^{-i {m} x}$ for $\partial^2f(x)+m^2f(x)=0$ where we have two constants to fix the one component for second order equation) -- it just seems to me that in case of four components first order equation we should have two more "constants" to play around with in the most general solution. (but maybe Lorentz invariance fixes things, once the 2-component solution to rest frame Weyl equation has been determined?)

Comment: I thought a bit about this and now I completely agree: The $u_+,u_-,v_+,v_-$ spinors are the four "constants" to play around with and parameterize the four linearly independent solutions to the Dirac equation. The $c$ and $d$ are the creation/annihilation operators which appear due to canonical quantization and operator property of the field (they have nothing to do with solutions to "classical" relativistic differential equation).

Comment: @Kagaratsch well I was thinking right now how to answer to your question from yesterday, but I guess it's clear already :-) glad to hear that